# Google Sheets: Find the value of the last filled cell in a column, format type is date

Tags: google-sheets

I want to to find the value of the last non-empty cell in a column with a formula. The column contains dates.

https://i.imgur.com/gVqTMyl.png

I have no idea how to use a formula for that.

This:
=+sort(D1:D; not(isblank(D1:D)) * row(D1:D); false)
returns no value.

Edit: This is what I want to achive:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Zz80.png

I want to get the difference in days between today and the last date in the column.

Date is stored in date format.

I want to calculate this:

=datedif(A5;today();"d")

Answer (score 1):

In case of valid date data use `MATCH()` function to find last non empty cell. Try-

```
=MATCH(99^9,A:A)
```

[image]

Comment: This gives me an error.

Comment: Are they true date or string stored as date.

Comment: @Intregal Use `Semicolon` instead of comma. Try `=MATCH(99^9;A:A)` It depends on region and language settings.

Comment: That formula gives me just a number, but I need the whole date to calculate the difference between the date and today.

Comment: For getting the matched value `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99^9;A:A))`. And then subtract it from the date you want.

Comment: @Intregal Number represent dates. So you need to subtract that date from `TODAY()` try `=TODAY()-  INDEX(A:A,MATCH(99^9;A:A))` then format your resultant cell as your desired date format.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(D:D;D:D);-1)
```

Comment: I think you mean: `=CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(D:D;D:D<>"");-1)`

Comment: Dates are non-zero numbers so they are truthy by default.

Comment: This seems to work if Iterative calculations is enabled.

Comment: @Intregal, you don't need iterative calculation for this.

Comment: If I don't activate iterative calculations I get an error:

"Mistake
A circular reference was detected. If you want to solve the formula by iterative calculation, you can choose it in File > Settings."

Comment: This is because you are entering the formula in column D. If you want to enter the formula in column D update the ranges `D:D` so that they don't contain the cell in which you've put the formula.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
=TODAY()-LOOKUP(2^99, A2:A)
```

> I want to get the difference in days between today and the last date in the column.

This solution shows that there are 1,040 days from the last date in the column, which is August 2, 2020, until today.

[image: Formula is found in B2.]